# Default landing page after login

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How can we change the default landing page pro-grammatically from a portlet. I need to change the landing page from a portlet. I tried to look into the `com.liferay.portlet.portalsettings.action.EditCompanyAction`
But there they are not updating the landing page.
How can I achieve the above functionality?
Or what is the class that is responsible for setting the default page from UI.

Comment: Is it about post login landing page?

Comment: Have a look at : https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/17676547

Comment: Hey Pankaj,
It is about the login landing page only.
I have seen that app. but that changes the landing page after login dynamically. But I want to set the page programmatically from a portlet. Is that possible??

Comment: I did not get it, can you please elaborate more on requirement

Comment: What I had to do is that I need to give a portlet to some user who can set the landing page post login. I need to give users,  list of pages and user will select the landing page from that list.

Comment: Ok, you may use custom-field(expando) of user to save landing page url, and also you can modify app to land user to user's custom field value

Comment: Hey Pankaj,  
Can you tell me the class where liferay updates this value??